# VBA Programmatically change object name

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls

I've created a date picker which allows you to select multiple dates, and toggle them so no-one can book anything on those days.

In order to do this, I have 31 toggle buttons, and a month selector.  When you select the month, each of the 31 buttons has to update, and get the value (toggled on or or) from a `DLookup`.

At the moment, I've got the code for this as a long list in the update event of the month picker

```
Private Sub cmbMonth_AfterUpdate()

    If IsNull(Me.cmbMonth) Then
        GoTo Subexit
    Else
        Imonth = CInt(Me.cmbMonth)
    End If

    Call Update_toggle(Me.Toggle1)
    Call Update_toggle(Me.Toggle2)
    Call Update_toggle(Me.Toggle3)
    Call Update_toggle(Me.Toggle4)
```

etc - up to toggle 31.

Is there a way of doing this with a loop?

I tried something along the lines of:

```
Dim toggle as Togglebutton
Dim I as integer
Dim strTogglename as String
set toggle = new togglebutton

I = 1

for 1 = 1 to 32

    strtogglename = "Me.Toggle" & I

    set toggle.name = strtogglename

    Call Update_toggle(Toggle)

next I
```

But I can't get it to work. Playing around with `byref` and `byval` don't seem to help.

Comment: What is the ```Me``` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Form's `Controls` collection and check the type of each control as you loop. You're looking for `acToggleButton`s.

```
Dim cntrl As Control
For Each cntrl In Me.Controls
    If cntrl.ControlType = acToggleButton Then

        Update_toggle cntrl

    End If
Next
```

Comment: I personally leave the stage to RubberDuck, his solution is way more efficient; this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: P.s. clearly, don't forget to manage an additional check in the case where your form contains other ToggleButtons that are not supposed to enter the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store your objects inside a global collection at initialize time, for example:

*Global Collection declaration*

```
Dim allToggles As Collection
```

*Initialize - storing objects in collection*

```
Set allToggles = New Collection
With allToggles
    .Add Me.Toggle1
    .Add Me.Toggle2
    '...
    .Add Me.Toggle31
End With
```

*Calling in loop*

```
for I = 1 to 32

    Update_toggle allToggles(I)

next I
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the loop, you are able to derive the names of your controls as `"Toggle" & I`.  So you can target the corresponding control *object* by referencing that item by name in the form's `Controls` collection.

```vb
'for 1 = 1 to 32
For I = 1 to 31
    Call Update_toggle(Me.Controls("Toggle" & I))
Next I
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know it is not possible to **programmatically** edit a control's name. To achieve that, one must be inside the VBA editor.
Only a caption may be edited in code.